# Get updated column in Cassandra using Hector Api

Tags: cassandra, hector, cassandra-cli

I am using scala with play framework. I've just started cassandra with Hectors. I have a function to delete a comparator of given key. But I want to know if comparator is actually  deleted or not.

Here is my function...

```
def delete()={
     var mutator=HFactory.createMutator(keyspace,StringSerializer)
     mutator.delete("MyKey","ColumnFamily","MyComparator",StringSerializer)
     val status=mutator.execute()
     println(status)

  }
```

if I print "status" variable  then it gives the same values whether comparator is deleted or not.

```
 MutationResult took (0us) for query (n/a) on host: [none]
```

Comment: Looks like you haven't specified any hosts when initialising hector. With that being said, Hector doesn't support the binary protocol, and knowing that the community is pushing CQL3 and abandoning thrift I'd invest some time to check for alternative drivers (but if you need a driver that is closer to the storage engine... Hector is great).

Comment: @LyubenTodorov I have specified host and keyspace like              val cluster = HFactory.getOrCreateCluster("Test Cluster", "192.168.1.2:9160");
val keyspace = HFactory.createKeyspace("mykeyspace", cluster)         But it's not working.

Comment: Yes,both the addresses are same. Everything is working properly insertion and deletion.But i want to know is there a way to know whether data is deleted or not from column family. In Mysql it returns  number of updated rows and we can know that whether a row is actually deleted or not. Is there any hector function to do this ??